# SSRS create a heatmap by coloring in the background color of a textbox in a Matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I created a Matrix that shows us how much times each item was sold by a certain period (i.e. daily, weekly, monthly, etc.

Here is what the matrix looks like without any of the colors filled in:

[image]

[image: sql]

What I want to do is turn this matrix into a sort of heatmap, where the higher the number is, the redder it is, compared to some sort of max value.

I am using the code I found here -> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40153.ssrs-how-to-apply-heat-map-color-formatting.aspx

```
Public Function HeatMapColorGradate( _
  ByVal Value As Double _
, ByVal MaxPositive As Double _
, ByVal Neutral As Double _
, ByVal ColStr As String) As String
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:  To use a color gradations on a heatmap report
' Example:  BackgroundColor =Code.HeatMapColorGradate(25, 100, -10, Variables!ColorEventCountGradate.Value)
'           BackgroundColor =Code.HeatMapColorGradate(dayValue, maxValue, 0, "#2322EE")
' Note:     Use a negative number as the "Neutral" number to avoid too light of a color
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Const Shd As Double = 255
Dim ColVar1      As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Left(Right(ColStr, 6), 2), 16)
Dim ColVar2      As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Left(Right(ColStr, 4), 2), 16)
Dim ColVar3      As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Right(ColStr, 2), 16) 'Find Largest Range 'Split the #RGB color to R, G, and B components
Dim decPosRange  As Double = Math.Abs(MaxPositive - Neutral) 'Find appropriate color shade
Dim iColor1      As Integer = ColVar1 + CInt(Math.Round((MaxPositive - Value) * ((Shd - ColVar1) / decPosRange)))
Dim iColor2      As Integer = ColVar2 + CInt(Math.Round((MaxPositive - Value) * ((Shd - ColVar2) / decPosRange)))
Dim iColor3      As Integer = ColVar3 + CInt(Math.Round((MaxPositive - Value) * ((Shd - ColVar3) / decPosRange))) 'Return the new color
Dim heatMapColor As String = "#" & iColor1.ToString("X2") & iColor2.ToString("X2") & iColor3.ToString("X2") 'Reduce a shade for each of the R,G,B components

    Return heatMapColor

End Function
```

It is a function that takes the current value and the max value, and colors the cell accordingly.

My problem is that for my Matrix, the value of the current textbox is =Sum(Fields!Touches.Value). However the textbox for the max value is exactly the same, =Sum(Fields!Touches.Value). But since it is under a different group, it produces a different result (the sum of the previous sums). So if I use those two values, I just get the same dark color in every textbox.

[image]

Maybe I am using the wrong value and Max value? Does anyone have any tips on how to do this?

Comment: would be way easier to return what the color should be in the dataset and then simply set the background color to the returned column in SSRS

Comment: I figured it out. You can specify the scope just like you can specify the dataset.